# Why does it come out as undefined?

Tags: javascript

When I run the flowing it throws `undefined`

```js
const coffees = [ 
    "light colombian roast", "hawaiian dark roast", "guatemalan blend medium roast",
    "madagascar espresso roast", "jamaican dark blue", "jamaican medium roast",
    "salvador robusto light", "bali espresso roast"
]
let selector = 0
const choiceLight = []
const choiceMedium = []
const choiceDark = []

for (const roast of coffees) {
    if (roast.includes("light")) {
      choiceLight.push(roast)
      console.log("I'll have the " + choiceLight[selector] + " and drink it black") 
    } else if (roast.includes("medium")) {
      choiceMedium.push(roast)
      console.log("I'll have the " + choiceMedium[selector] + " and add cream only")
    } else if (roast.includes("dark") || roast.includes("espresso")) {
      choiceDark.push(roast)
      console.log("I'll have the " + choiceDark[selector] + " and add cream and sugar" )
    }
    selector++
}

/*
I'll have the light colombian roast and drink it black
I'll have the undefined and add cream and sugar
I'll have the undefined and add cream only
I'll have the undefined and add cream and sugar
I'll have the undefined and add cream and sugar
I'll have the undefined and add cream only
I'll have the undefined and drink it black
I'll have the undefined and add cream and sugar
*/
```

Comment: Hey! The code snippet has a syntax error in it - I think you need to make the results (I'll...) into comments. The question also might benefit from a more descriptive title :)

Answer (score 2):

You are pushing data in a different array. Push will push after last data. So index will not be same.
For example: In second data, you push in `choiceMedium` so index will be `0`, However `selector` will be `1`. So `undefined`.

**Correct implementation:**

```js
const coffees = [
  "light colombian roast",
  "hawaiian dark roast",
  "guatemalan blend medium roast",
  "madagascar espresso roast",
  "jamaican dark blue",
  "jamaican medium roast",
  "salvador robusto light",
  "bali espresso roast",
];
let selector = 0;
const choiceLight = [];
const choiceMedium = [];
const choiceDark = [];

for (const roast of coffees) {
  if (roast.includes("light")) {
    choiceLight.push(roast);
    console.log(
      "I'll have the " + roast + " and drink it black"
    );
  } else if (roast.includes("medium")) {
    choiceMedium.push(roast);
    console.log(
      "I'll have the " + roast + " and add cream only"
    );
  } else if (roast.includes("dark") || roast.includes("espresso")) {
    choiceDark.push(roast);
    console.log(
      "I'll have the " + roast + " and add cream and sugar"
    );
  }
  selector++;
}
```

```css
.as-console {
  min-height: 100% !important;
}

.as-console-row {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you, it worked. I made this complicated for no reason and added things I didn't need. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

On the first iteration `selector` equals zero. No problem. You append the given variety to a choice array and print its **0 indexed element**.(first position)

On the second iteration `selector` equals 1. Unless it belongs to the same choice array as the previus iteration, you will append it to an empty array and request it's **1 indexed element** (so, the one in second position). It doesn't exist.

In any scenario where you find a variety that doesn't belong to the same choice as the previous one, your array indexes will never match your selector value ever again.

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing `selector` each time you go through the loop, but you are pushing only one item into each array. Therefore each item will be at position 0 in each of the arrays. If you keep `selector` at 0, it should work

Answer (score 0):

why do you need to use "selector" at all?
you can just push "roast" and print the "roast" comment

as was mentioned you have separate lists but using one index "selector" across all your loop iterations

if you want to use a "selector" you can use one per roast type being tracked: ltSelector, mdSelector, dkSelector.